# Database Collation difference UTF? Latin? etc.?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, collation

What is the collation usage for a database? Well for HTML UTF-8 I know a bit, like for displaying other language type. But what about for a database? I'm using latin-1 (default), my friends told me to use UTF instead. When I ask why, they don't know and say that others use it. So I'm questioning what does collation really do? Does it affect speed or something like that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MySQL confuses the issue by having collations named after character encodings.  They're separate concepts.

A [**collation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation) determines how the relational operators (`<`, `>`, etc.) and `ORDER BY` clauses sort strings.  Issues considered by collations are:

- Are uppercase and lowercase letters considered equivalent?
- Is whitespace significant?
- Do accented letters sort equal to the unaccented versions, after the unaccented versions, or at the end?
- Are digraphs like "ch" and "ll" sorted like separate letters?
- Are Unicode compatibility equivalents like AᴬⒶＡ treated the same?

Some of these depend on the language.

A [**character encoding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) determines how text values get converted to and from byte sequences.  For a good introduction, see [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

There are hundreds of different character encodings, most of the specific to a certain combination of operating system and locale.  Most of them are supersets of [US-ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), so *if* you're *damn sure* your data will be ASCII-only, it doesn't matter what encoding you use.

But if you need other characters, you need an encoding that can handle them.  For Western languages, your choices are generally:

- Single-byte encodings, of which the most common is [ISO-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).  I think MySQL's Latin1 encoding is actually [windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which is similar.
- UTF-8, which is [very popular these days](http://w3techs.com/technologies/overview/character_encoding/all).

The difference between the two is:

- For Western European accented characters, UTF-8 requires 2 bytes while Latin-1 requires only 1 byte.
- But other characters can't be represented in Latin-1 at all.  UTF-8 can represent every possible Unicode character.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have confused the term **charset** and **collation**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-general.html

A **character set** is a set of symbols and encodings. A **collation** is a set of rules for comparing characters in a character set.

latin1 and utf8 are valid charsets in MySQL, while latin1_swedish_ci and utf8_general_ci are example collations.

Answer (score 1):

[See this on Answers](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_collation_in_MySQL_Database) about collations. About character sets and codepages see wikipedia. FYI [latin1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin1) is suitable for english and west european countries. [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8) is suitable for a universal application that may contain for example Chinese, or Arabic text.

Comment: certain languages need more than one byte to represent a character. So  UTF-8 is a variable-length character encoding. This has performance implications (both space/memory and speed). If you really need international support though there is no alternative.

Comment: if im a startup what will you choose ? btw if im not supporting internaional (english) latin1 is just fine ? thanks

Comment: If you only handle English then any codepage (including latin1 and utf-8) will do.

Comment: I'll bet you €20 that someday you'll encounter non-ISO-8859-1 characters in English text.

Comment: @dan04 hahaha, ok i think its better useing utf_ then :|

Comment: @dan04 I agree unicode is mandatory in this day and age. 8bit charsets are a relic but .. you know relics have a way of hanging on indefinitely in our business.

Comment: I know what you mean.  Even EBCDIC isn't dead yet, as I know from personal experience :(

Answer (score 1):

Database collation controls how strings are compared / sorted - and at a lower level how the stored character data is interpreted.  Latin-1 will allow strings in the latin-1 code page to be stored / compared.  If you need to handle e.g. Japanese text then UTF-8 is a much better choice.

Comment: so it will effect the storage ?

Comment: Yes - it will have an effect on the storage and the speed of data access - storing a typical Unicode character will require > 1 byte of storage storing most 'usual' Western characters will require just a single byte.

Comment: whats the smallest and fastest coll ? latin1 ? i bet the most support chars + heavy is utf ( its mili sec difference i bet? )

Comment: ups i think im wrong http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/c0053263.html >The collation you choose can significantly impact the performance

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking, the database collation will effect sorting of character data.  The reason to go with UTF-8, would be because you're storing UTF-8 data.

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding of data.  data itself is not UTF-8, or any other encoding.